# Display all object values in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to display all the values in an object but it give me 'must be declared' error.

I tried the code below but still giving me same error.

```
declare
      outN mytype;
begin
      outN:= get_data();
      dbms_output.put_line(outN.toString);
      -- tried this as well
      dbms_output.put_line(outN.ID);
      dbms_output.put_line(outN.G);
      dbms_output.put_line(outN.GES);
      dbms_output.put_line(outN.CC);
      dbms_output.put_line(outN.RR);

end;
```

And my object is:

```
 create or replace TYPE           "mytype"
    AS OBJECT
    (
        "ID" NUMBER(10),
        "G" NUMBER(10),
        "GES"  VARCHAR(100 BYTE),
        "CC" NUMBER(10),
        "RR" VARCHAR(100 BYTE)
    );
```

Errors:

> Error report -
>       ORA-06550: line 5, column 38:
>       PLS-00302: component 'ID' must be declared
>       ORA-06550: line 5, column 7:
>       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>       ORA-06550: line 6, column 38:
>       PLS-00302: component 'G' must be declared
>       ORA-06550: line 6, column 7:
>       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>       ORA-06550: line 7, column 38:
>       PLS-00302: component 'GES' must be declared
>       ORA-06550: line 7, column 7:
>       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>       ORA-06550: line 8, column 38:
>       PLS-00302: component 'CC' must be declared
>       ORA-06550: line 8, column 7:
>       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>       ORA-06550: line 9, column 38:
>       PLS-00302: component 'RR' must be declared
>       ORA-06550: line 9, column 7:
>       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>       06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>       *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Another one:

> Error report -
>       ORA-06550: line 5, column 38:
>       PLS-00302: component 'TOSTRING' must be declared
>       ORA-06550: line 5, column 7:
>       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>       06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>       *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>       *Action:

`get_data` is just a function that return the result of a select statement (returns db rows)

Comment: What is `toString`? I don't see an attribute (or method) of type `mytype` in its definition. In any case, the first error will be thrown at the name of the type. You declared it as `"mytype"`. In Oracle, when you use double-quotes, you are saying that you want case-sensitive identifiers. By default Oracle is not case sensitive; it will automatically convert `mytype` in your code block to `MYTYPE`, which will not match `"mytype"`. Get in the habit of **not** using double-quoted identifiers, they only bring trouble. The alternative is in the declarations section to use double quotes.

Comment: What is `get_data()`, also? There is a call to it in your code, but you haven't shown us what it is. ALSO: If you need help, you will have to include the exact error message(s) in your posts. Right now, the type `MYTYPE` is not declared (lower-case `"mytype"` is, which is different), but you will likely get more errors - tell us exactly what they are.

Comment: edit my question

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't believe you. If you define the type `"mytype"` but you reference it without double-quotes, you will not get to the "undeclared components", you will get the error `PLS-00201: identifier 'MYTYPE' must be declared` first.

Comment: well, this is the error I got, why will I lie??

Comment: I don't think you are lying, you are just not realizing what you are doing. Are you really declaring the type in double quotes, and is it really lower case? Are you really referencing it without double quotes? I don't believe all three questions have the answer "yes". Do they?

Comment: Unless... did you also (perhaps in the past) create a type `MYTYPE`? Which may still exist in your schema (or a schema you have privileges to)? What do you get if you `select * from ALL_TYPES where UPPER(type_name) = 'MYTYPE'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what `get_data()` and `toString` are in your code. But, this should explain how object values can be displayed.

```
create or replace TYPE  mytype -- removed double quotes
    AS OBJECT
    (
        "ID"   NUMBER(10),
        "G"    NUMBER(10),
        "GES"  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), --Use VARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR
        "CC"   NUMBER(10),
        "RR"   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
    );
    /
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON    
DECLARE
     outn   mytype := mytype(1,10,'GES1',20,'RR1'); --declaration and assignment
BEGIN
     dbms_output.put_line(outn.id);
     dbms_output.put_line(outn.g);
     dbms_output.put_line(outn.ges);
     dbms_output.put_line(outn.cc);
     dbms_output.put_line(outn.rr);
END;
/
```

**Result**

```
Type MYTYPE compiled

1
10
GES1
20
RR1


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: thanks @Kaushik, I am not sure why did you remove double quotes? My code is working fine with the double quotes but and returning the data fine with no error but the problem is to display the data of the object.

Comment: When I run your code I get :
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 6, column 38:
PLS-00302: component 'ID' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 7, column 38:
PLS-00302: component 'G' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 7, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 8, column 38:
PLS-00302: component 'GES' must be declared

Comment: ORA-06550: line 8, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 9, column 38:
PLS-00302: component 'CC' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 9, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 10, column 38:
PLS-00302: component 'RR' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 10, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @SMH : your error message indicates the the object has not been declared correctly. As you can see it works for me fine. Either there's something wrong with your `get_data()` function or you aren't  showing us everything.